# the side of my letters are not getting remeshed

Tags: mesh, modifiers, remesh

So i made text and with remesh modifier i am trying to remesh it so i can sculpt it.
The problem i am having is the side of my letters are not getting any mesh so i cant sculpt them properly **can anyone help me**.

[image: side of letter without the mesh]

Comment: How did you thicken it - did you extrude through the text data properties, convert to mesh and extrude, or did you use a Solidify Modifier?

Comment: i did it in geometry > extrude 
and i retried in a new file with solidify both dident work

Comment: Strange.. I can't reproduce the problem. I wonder if it's a function of the font you're using. Are you using something special?

Comment: uhm i imported it from an svg file that i made in illustrator

Comment: That's odd. I tried with an svg using all combinations of the above mentioned methods (as well as a few more), and I still can's reproduce your problem. I'm wondering though, is it that your sides have _no_ faces, or is it that they have a very huge amount of faces (as a result of the remesh), that can't be seen until you zoom in very close? I only mention it, because the sides should be "clear" if they have no internal subdivisions, but for some reason they are orange like all the selected edges which makes me wonder if it's just really "dense".

Comment: yea that could be posible it my first day using blender
u have any tips on how i could make the sides less

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your actual project. I'm not even sure I'm even right about what's going on - it just _looks_ that way.

Comment: im pretty sure u are right could i maybe add u on discord and hop in a quick call

Comment: Sorry, I don't do discord. If you want to upload your file (or a minimal version of it) so people can have a better chance to diagnose your problem, you can upload it here - https://blend-exchange.com/. Just copy the link they give you, edit your question (on this page) and paste in the link.